# Is this UPDATE statement valid? it is giving me error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting error in the below query. Can someone please help in identifying the error if any?

```
UPDATE TOP(1) Customers SET FirstName = 'ted' where LastName = 'Miller'
```

Comment: Please post the error. If you have an error, your statement is for sure not valid.

Comment: "Can someone please help in identifying the error" - the error almost certainly goes to some effort to help you identify it/help - such as error *numbers* or just the error *message*. Both of these are noticeably absent from your question. You don't just get a message saying `ERROR` and nothing else.

Comment: What error exactly? Please [edit] your question and paste the exact error message.

Comment: Usea ROW_NUMBER in a CTE and update that.What you have is not valid sql

Comment: Please post error message.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Ann...yes it is solved now

Answer (score 0):

You can't say `UPDATE TOP(1)` in an update statement.

If you have multiple rows where `LastName = 'Miller'`, but only want to update the top one, you need to specify further conditions in your `where` clause until only that one row is returned.

Having said that, this may be what you're looking for:

```
UPDATE Customers
   SET FirstName = 'ted'
WHERE Id IN (
   SELECT  TOP 1 Id
   FROM    Customers
   WHERE   LastName = 'Miller'
)
```

I am inferring that your row has an `Id` field or some other field to uniquely identify the `Customer` row.  If it doesn't, you have bigger problems than just this one UPDATE statement.

Also, because I didn't specify an `ORDER BY` in the subquery (and neither did you in your attempted `UPDATE` statement), what row turns out to be the "top one" is completely arbitrary.  You'll get *much more reliable results* if you include an `ORDER BY` to *tell* it how to determine which row is "top".